# System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException on EF Database.EnsureDeleted() and Database.EnsureCreated() methods

Tags: xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I get this problem, when I call the `Database.EnsureDeleted()` and `Database.EnsureCreated()` methods.:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters
>   specified does not match the expected number.

Here the init code of EF in a Xamarin Forms project.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string _dbPath;

        public DatabaseContext (string dbPath = null) : base()
        {
            _dbPath = dbPath ?? App.DatabasePath;
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
  }
```

And under the Android project here the code:

```
 LoadApplication(new App());
            App.DatabasePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "database.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 0):

> _dbPath = dbPath ?? App.DatabasePath;

You are using a ternary operator, so you need to provide 2 resulting elements:

> _dbPath = dbPath ?? App.DatabasePath : dbPath;

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Visual studio does not show the full exceptions for Xamarin.Forms.
Make sure to surround your code with try clause, and read the full exception message.
for me, the problem solved by including Id field (Primary Key) in HasData method.